# How to Use Lalavel mix with angular for development

Tags: angular, laravel

I have setting up Laravel mix with Angular 4 . as per doc i have run `npm run dev` also `npm run watch` . after that i have run `php artisan serve` and `gulp watch` also .. nowi have made some changes on typescript but its not reflect .

i have tried  `php artisan serve` for port 8000
also `gulp watch` running 3000
but type script changes not reflect

here is the laravel mix code :

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "node ./node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "node ./node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "hot": "node ./node_modules/cross-env/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "production": "node ./node_modules/cross-env/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor",
    "precache": "sw-precache --verbose --config=sw-precache-config.js"
  },
```

No error on `gulp watch` , `npm run dev or watch` and `php atrtisan serve`